# ANR due to timeout on Broadcast sent by one app to other app

Tags: android

I have two apps. One being **Collector** and one being **Uplaoder**. Collector collects some data and send via broadcast to Uploader which uploads to the server.
Now the problems is sometimes when Collector sends broadcast to Uplaoder ,the broadcast times out and throws ANR. 
I have already checked in my Uploader app that there is no heavy work is going on which affects the timeout. It just starts a Service thats all.

Here is the exception 
[image]

Here is the Uplaoder broadcast reciever

```
public class DataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = DataReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AndroidApplication application = (AndroidApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    if (BuildVersionsHelper.isBuildVersionMAndAbove()) {
        if (!application.isSystemUser()) {
            return;
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Event upload request through DataReceiver");
    JobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, SimpleInterfaceReceiverService.class,
            Constants.SIMPLE_INTERFACE_JOB, intent);
}}
```

Manifest where the broadcast reciver is added

```
 <receiver android:name=".intentreceiver.DataReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.symbol.dataanalytics.TRANSPORT_INTENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Collector code which sends the broadcast

```
Bundle eventBundle = new Bundle();
    Intent intent = new Intent(EVENT_ACTION);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(TIMESTAMP, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    intent.putExtra(DATA, eventBundle);
    intent.putExtra(TYPE, eventName);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setData(null);
    intent.setPackage("com.xxx.Uploader");
    intent.setAction("com.xxx.xxx.TRANSPORT_INTENT");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Now these timeouts are warnings but why these are showing ANRs in the app?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the root cause of this.

The reason here is that the Collector app is doing too much of work on the main thread which is clear in the logs. I can see that the CPU load is 11% due to the Collector app.

Now the same time **Collector** app tries to send a broadcast to the **Uploader** app. As the **Collector** is running heavily on the CPU more that expected Android os is marking it critical hence the braodcast being sent from **Collector to Uploader** is being delayed or not reacher to the destination. Now the broadcast has not returned withing 10secs due to which os is raising an ANR on the receiver app (i.e. **Uploader**) thinking it  has not returned the broadcast from onRecieve whithin speculated time.

**NOTE** : I am still not sure about the theory of having ANR raised on the receiver end even if the sender has some issues. Please correct me if i am wrong.